# Javascript: if (x < y) works, if(x<=y) does not work.

Tags: javascript, operators, equals

if (x < y) works, if(x<=y) does not work in Javascript. In the former case the if-statement is evaluated, in the later case the if-staement is ignored.

Here's the code:

```
var totalFrames = 12;
```

Here the showvalue functiion receives its value from HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="2" max="36" step="2" value="2" name="totalFrames" 
      onChange="showValue(this.value);" width: 80%" value="2"/>
<p>Total Frames: <span id="totalFrames">2</span> 


function showValue(newValue) {
         document.getElementById("totalFrames").innerHTML = parseFloat(newValue);
         totalFrames = parseInt(newValue);
         var winkel = 360.0/totalFrames;
         document.getElementById("angle").innerHTML = winkel.toFixed(1);
         var maxFrame = document.getElementsByName("actFrame")[0];
         maxFrame.max = parseInt(newValue);
}

function motorCommunication() { 
      actFrame = document.getElementById("actFrame").value;
      actualFrame = parseInt(document.getElementById("actFrame").value);
      document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = actFrame;
```

/* THIS LINE DOES WORK -- The if statement is NOT ignored*/

```
if ( Number(actualFrame) < Number(totalFrames) ) {
```

/* THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK -- The if statement is ignored*/

```
if ( Number(actualFrame) <= Number(totalFrames) ) {

     var url = "/cgi-bin/bn_events.py?actualFrame=" + escape(actualFrame) 
         + "&totalFrames=" + escape(totalFrames) 
         + "&seconds=" + escape(seconds);
     request.open("GET", url, true);
     request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
     request.send(null);
     actualFrame++;
  }
  else {
       document.getElementById("returnedStatus").value = "DONE.";
  }
}

function updatePage() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      /* Get the response from the server */
      var motorResponse = request.responseText;
      motorData = new Array();
      //motorData = request.responseText;
      motorData = motorResponse.substring(0,motorResponse.length-1).split(",");
      /* Update the HTML web form */
      document.getElementById("returnedFrame").value = motorData[0];
      document.getElementById("returnedTotalFrames").value = motorData[1]
      document.getElementById("returnedStatus").value = motorData[2];
      document.getElementById("actFrame").value = parseInt(actualFrame);
      document.getElementById("actualStatus").value = parseInt(actualFrame);     
      setTimeout(motorCommunication(),300);
      } else {
      alert("Error! Request status is " + request.status);
      }
    }
}
```

What I found out is, that if I use

```
if ( Number(actualFrame) <= 12 ) {
```

it works perfectly....

Helpless now...
Appreciate any comment.

Comment: If I use Number() or parseInt() or parseFloat() does not matter...

Comment: What is the output if you log both number before the if-statement?

Comment: @JohnKugelman It wouldn't work at all if it was.

Comment: I'll bet your issue is in IE. The fix is probably to declare variables to keep them local, you have an element with an ID that is the same as an implicit global (totalFrames). Note that when you declare it globally, the issue is "fixed".

Comment: Yes it is inside a <script> tag. The logs show the numbers...

Comment: No the issue is in safari...

Comment: Same thing in google chrome.

Comment: Safari emulates IE and makes element IDs properties of the global object. Chrome likely does the same as they're both based on Webkit.

Comment: Same thing in google chrome. I globally declared the variable totalFrames now with window.totalFrames inside the functions. Did not help.

Comment: Works perfect with "<=" in Firefox.... What is the work around in IE?

Comment: Well to be precise: FF21. It does not work in the nightly build FF23... Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed... Had nothing to do with str to Int or similar... 
The if-statement was on the wrong position. So some variables were just screwed up.

```
function motorCommunication() {
         /* NEEDS TO BE HERE... */
         if ( actualFrame <= lastFrame * 1.0 ) {
         actFrame = document.getElementById("actFrame").value;
         actualFrame = parseInt(document.getElementById("actFrame").value);
         document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = actFrame * 1.0;  
         //lastFrame = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("totalFrames")[0].value); 
         document.getElementById("returnedTotalFrames").value = lastFrame * 1.0;
         //WRONG HERE: if ( actualFrame <= lastFrame * 1.0 ) {
            var url = "/cgi-bin/bn_events.py?actualFrame=" + escape(actualFrame) 
            + "&totalFrames=" + escape(lastFrame) 
            + "&seconds=" + escape(seconds);
            //var url = "/cgi-bin/bn_events.py?actualFrame=" + escape(actFrame);
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
            request.send(null);
            actualFrame++;
            } else {
            document.getElementById("returnedStatus").value = "DONE.";
         }
}
```

Works better now. Independent from the Browser...

Thanks for all your help. Peter